# Why can't I update HiddenFields on PostBack?

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, webforms

This is my code :

```
private string[] MesiSelezionati;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MesiSelezionati = new string[] { "2", "4" };
    UpdateMesi();
}

override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl meseItem = new HtmlGenericControl("a") { InnerHtml = "mese" };
        meseItem.Attributes.Add("href", "javascript:void(0);");

        HiddenField hf = new HiddenField();
        hf.Value = "0";
        hf.ID = "idMese_" + i.ToString();

        meseItem.Controls.Add(hf);

        panelMesi.Controls.Add(meseItem);
    }

    base.OnInit(e);
}

private void UpdateMesi()
{
    foreach (HtmlGenericControl a in panelMesi.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>())
    {
        HiddenField hf = a.Controls.OfType<HiddenField>().LastOrDefault();
        if (MesiSelezionati.Contains(hf.ID.Split('_').LastOrDefault()))
        {
            hf.Value = "1";
            a.Attributes.Add("class", "box-ricerca-avanzata-item link-box selected");
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the page, all is ok! The problem is when I call the same page (so, postback) thanks to a asp:LinkButton. I get a `System.NullReferenceException` on `if (MesiSelezionati.Contains(hf.ID.Split('_').LastOrDefault()))`.

Seems that the HiddenField of the 2° and 4° link (which corrispond to the position at `MesiSelezionati = new string[] { "2", "4" };`) are null. Why? And how can I fix it?

## EDIT : code for Mark M

```
HtmlGenericControl optionBox = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
optionBox.Attributes["class"] = "option-box";

HtmlGenericControl optionBoxItem = new HtmlGenericControl("a") { InnerHtml = "&nbsp;" };
optionBoxItem.Attributes.Add("href", "javascript:void(0);");
optionBoxItem.Attributes.Add("class", "option-box-item");

HtmlGenericControl optionBoxTesto = new HtmlGenericControl("a") { InnerText = Categoria.Categoria };
optionBoxTesto.Attributes.Add("href", "javascript:void(0);");
optionBoxTesto.Attributes.Add("class", "option-box-testo");

HiddenField hf = new HiddenField();
hf.Value = "0";
hf.ID = "categoria_" + Categoria.UniqueID;

optionBox.Controls.Add(optionBoxItem);
optionBox.Controls.Add(optionBoxTesto);
optionBox.Controls.Add(hf);

panelCategorieGuida.Controls.Add(optionBox);
```

Comment: this is really bizzare! I really I can't figure out why this behaviour :O Looks like it lost, on postback, the updated controls at Page_Load, the first time I called it?????? Damn...

Comment: what makes you think it is the update? you should rather check where the null reference occurs and why

Comment: Uhm.. there isn't any reason on having HiddenFields null, on postback. This is the problem that I don't understand. On postback, HiddenField on 2° and 4° links (the one which values has been updated calling the page the first time) are null. Why? And This is what I need to fix..

Comment: P.S. they are updated, yes! When I call the page first time, I see the values to "1", not "0". So the problem is, in fact, on postback...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update hidden fields on postback, just not before Load. When executing OnInit, the controls have not been populated using the request & view state values. Your updates are being overwritten.

EDIT: I found the root cause of your issue & learned something in the process.

1. You set the InnerHtml property of the anchor tag (`InnerHtml = "mese"`) in the OnInit method.  Under the covers this assignment is `ViewState["innerhtml"] = "mese"`.
2. You assign a css class to the anchor after ViewState tracking has begun, so the ViewState restoration machinery will apply to this control on postback.

When you postback the anchor tags with added css classes will be subject to HtmlContainerControl.LoadViewState (which occurs between InitComplete and PreLoad).  If the LoadViewState method detects that ViewState["innerhtml"] has a value it wipes out all of the control's child controls (calling Controls.Clear()) and creates a LiteralControl to contain the innerhtml value, adding it as the sole child control.

Basically this means that you cannot set both the InnerHtml property and add any controls to a descendant of HtmlContainerControl if that control will ever be subject to ViewState tracking.

To fix your example; instead of setting InnerHtml to add the link text, create a LiteralControl with the desired text and add it to the anchor's child control collection.

Comment: I think this is not so true. It's bizzare, because on another context (with same code, but "div" instead of "a") works.. :O

Comment: Also, the problem is when I do the postback, not when I call the page (in fact, calling the page on Load, it UPDATE the values). :O

Comment: Well, since it only occurred on postback I suspected something to do with loading view state, so I inserted a number of lifecycle event handlers to narrow down when the issue was occurring.  Once I got it down to between the InitComplete and Load events I was 97% sure it was LoadViewState so I downloaded JetBrains decompiler and worked backward from the HtmlGenericControl until I found the class that implemented LoadViewState & examined it.  The `a` was subject to it because you added the class attribute to it after view state tracking was activated (active from Load through PreRender).

Comment: But on my other code, which I have `div` instead of `a`, I also apply a `class` attribute to it, and I use InnerHtml... but without any problems :O

Comment: I'd have to see the details of the `div` usage and class assignment.

Comment: News about this trouble? I'm curios :)

Comment: Sorry, I think I missed something - where is the code with the div issue?

Comment: the same code, with innerhtml and addclass. Just replace "a" with "div" :)

Comment: I get the same result.  Are you sure you didn't change the type in UpdateMesi's `panelMesi.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>` call?  Are you getting correct class attributes in your 2nd and 4th elements when you view source? I even re-copied your posted code from above to make sure I didn't make any changes when I was working with it before and still saw the same behavior as when "a" was used as the tag.

Comment: Sorry for the delay man! I was busy! Well, update my answer with "EDIT" for you, so you can see the code with div.! I use InnerHTML as well, but here it works. Why in the link not? What's the differences? Looks the same...

Comment: Good to hear from you again!  I thought you were gone!  If I understand your edit, I don't see these as comparable.  The initial problem was that you had a container item that you were dynamically adding children to and you were setting the innerHTML of the container at the same time, so the container was keeping only the innerHTML and obliterating the children.  In your edit it looks like the container has added children, but no innerHTML set.  It is the combination of the container having innerHTML and children that is the bad mix.  (See follow-up comment for rest - running out of space)

Comment: Now if your update had one or both of the anchor tags inserting a child element AND keeping the innerHTML property you would run into issues with that/those anchor tag(s) wiping out the children added to them and just displaying the innerHTML.  In your example the container only has children and the anchor tags only have innerHTML.  Does that clarify things?

Comment: Not really! You said : "It is the combination of the container having innerHTML and children that is the bad mix". But on my update example, `optionBoxItem` add children and also innerHTML, but it doesnt create any troubles. That's what I don't understand :)

Comment: In your example `optionBoxItem` doesn't have any children, only attributes.

Comment: You are right! Now I see what is the problem! Resuming : I add children and innerhtml, at the start! This is not problem. On PostBack, I recreate these; loading ViewState, it see there is a InnerHtml attribute on container, and "remove all children", putting that InnerHtml control value. So, the children are vanished, and of course they are "Null". Right?

Comment: Well! So the question is spontaneous : why, after cleaning children with InnerHTML, it doesnt care about previous children? Restore viewstate means restore "values", not "delete" object/elements (which they should be updated). The mechanism is bizzare, imo :)

Comment: I think the better choice would be to throw an exception, rather than defaulting to a behavior that is unlikely to be in line with the coder's intent.  InnerHTML and adding child controls are 2 different and completely independent ways of populating a control with child content.  There is no automatic way of determining what I want if I set InnerHTML and add child controls (do I want the InnerHTML content first or last?, did I get confused and only mean use one of the 2 options?), therefore an exception should be thrown, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

is your link button in some separate panel control? Can it be the case that you are doing partial postback, with AJAX? Sorry for answering with the question.